# Passive WiFi sniffing without associating to the AP

Tags: wifi, sniffer

Suppose that I have a WiFi adapter that is in range of several APs and clients, all sharing the same channel and all using WPA2 encryption. I know all their passwords. I'd like to sniff on all of them simultaneously. As I understand, I can decrypt traffic for each client as long as I can capture that client's handshake, I don't actually have to be associated to any of the APs.

I know that I can capture everything using wireshark, or capture with airodump-ng and then decrypt with airdecap-ng (and then somehow go through decrypted packets by hand?), but that's too much manual labor. Or I can use something like bettercap, and it'll do everything I need on the fly, but it wants to be associated to a particular AP, because it is designed mainly as a man-in-the-middle tool.

Are there any other tools that would sniff and decrypt the traffic (to the extent it can be decrypted), reporting e.g. observed HTTP requests in real time?

Comment: What's wrong with Wireshark for this purpose?

Comment: I would also point out that if you are in range of several APs, then you will likely have APs/clients on multiple channels. To not miss any traffic, you would need to have the adapter you are using configured to a specific channel. You may need multiple adapters (one per channel) to capture all the traffic in the area.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you are asking two different things here:

- Can I log all wifi traffic which I can physically pick up in a specific location, i.e. where I am within the range of both sender and receiver?
- If so: Depending on the amount of networks and traffic, this will yield a substantial amout of raw data (haystack) in which you need to look for whatever you are interested in (needle). Are there any tools which can help me with that?

I don't know of any specific tools, but you could start by writing some scripts which will create a folder for each station you are reading and put files in there. Other than that, look for big data tools. Elasticsearch might be a starting point to identify packets which are of interest to you.